# AngularJS pegar o $scope e concatenar em uma URL

Tags: angularjs, scope

app.js

```
    angular.module("FipeApp", []);

angular.module("FipeApp").controller("FipeAppCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.app = "FIPE APP";
  $scope.tipos = [{
    nome: "Carros",
    id: "carros"
  }, {
    nome: "Motos",
    id: "motos"
  }, {
    nome: "Caminhões",
    id: "caminhoes"
  }, ];

  //$scope.tipo = [];
  $scope.tipoSelec = '';

  //$scope.marca = [];
  //$scope.marcaSelec = '';

  var carregarMarcas = function() {
    $http.get('https://crossorigin.me/http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/' + $scope.tipoSelec + '/marcas.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.marcas = data;
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
    });
  };

  carregarMarcas();

});
```

index.html

```
<html lang="pt-BR" ng-app="FipeApp">
<body ng-controller="FipeAppCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="linha">
      <div class="coluna-5">
        <h4 class="header">{{app}}</h4>
        <select ng-model="tipoSelec" ng-change="carregarMarcas()" ng-options="tipo.nome for tipo in tipos">
          <option value="">Seleciona um Tipo de Veiculo</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="marcaSelec" ng-disabled="!tipoSelec" ng-options="marca.fipe_name for marca in marcas">
          <option value="">Seleciona uma Marca</option>
        </select>
        {{tipoSelec.id}} {{marcaSelec.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Preciso pegar o **tipoSelec.id** selecionado pelo cliente e concatenar na URL que vai pegar o JSON com o nome das Marcas, tentei de varias formas já e nda, sou noob ainda =)

[CODEPEN AQUI](http://codepen.io/juninhothiesen/pen/pjBNde)

Comment: É isso que você quer? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGVrbj

Comment: isso mesmo, só tive que ajustar a função do ng-click! valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque `var carregarMarcas = function()` para `$scope.carregarMarcas`

```
$scope.carregarMarcas = function() {
    $http.get('https://crossorigin.me/http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/' + $scope.tipoSelec.id + '/marcas.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.marcas = data;
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
    });
};

  $scope.carregarMarcas();
```

Exemplo funcionando:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGVrbj

Comment: Só tive que ajustar a ng-click vou dar continuidade no projeto.